# Capacitor with four pins

Tags: capacitor

What is the correct name for the four pin capacitor shown in the diagram?  It is an LMH0341.

[image]

Comment: if the question has no image it will not make any sense

Answer (score 4):

It is called SMD EMI/RFI filter - Feed through capacitor.

Comment: While I tend to agree in this case, there are also 4-terminals X2Y caps that look similar from the outside. But they have a substantially different pinout. The X2Y caps can be also used in-place of a feedthrough cap, but have to be rotated 90° for that.

Comment: Agree with this comment.  Those 4-terminal X2Y caps have lower inductance than a standard 2-terminal cap, and so find use in places where switching noise cause by fast rise and fall time signals needs to be reduced as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Texas Instruments' LMH0341](https://www.ti.com/product/LMH0341) is an SDI deserializer; the [Application Report SNLA302](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla302/snla302.pdf) provides guidelines on how to reduce EMI in designs that use TI serializers and deserializers.

Section 4 Power and Grounding (page 5, 6/8) reads

> - Place high-quality X7R decoupling capacitors close to device pins.
>   – Use multiple capacitors (0.1-μF, 0.01-μF, and 1-μF) in parallel to    offer low impedance over higher frequency ranges.

The use of a feedthru capacitor C47 in the design of your question enables the designer to manage with only one capacitor. Placing an 0.1uF decoupling capacitor with X7R dielectric, [W2H13C1048ATxx (page 1, 3/12)](https://datasheets.avx.com/L2FL3F.pdf), (capacitor C47) enables the designer to use a single component, rather than multiple capacitors. The unique construction of a feedthru capacitor provides low parallel inductance and offers excellent decoupling capability for all high di/dt environments, essentially reducing noise in digital circuits to <5 GHz. Conventional two-terminal capacitors only provide decoupling capability and noise reduction in significantly narrower ranges and the designer should use multiple two-terminal capacitors, varying in capacitance and connected in parallel, to cover the range this wide (5GHz).